# Downloading an image from php page

Tags: php

So i have this one small thing im doing, and the thing is: It generates QRcodes using the google qrcode api. Id like to download the generated qr code with the press of a button into a /img folder i have inside the folder my php file is located at, and id need it to save with a numerical number which is the button's id. (it has like 120 buttons and each one has a 0-120 id, id like to save the qrcode that belongs to the button 10 with a name like 10.png) any ideas on how to do so?

__

Little edit: as Man Manam pointed out my question is: I have the image link, i want to save it in my server. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Were you successful to generate QR code? I mean is your question like this: I have an URL of an image and I want to save that in my server? am I right?

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the bad description my english is not the best and i typed in a bit of a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Google for creating the QR code, I assume you have a code like this somewhere:

```
$ga = new \Google\Authenticator\GoogleAuthenticator();
$qr_link = $ga->getUrl($username, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $secret);
// then you'd display that code with <img src="$qr_link">
```

What you need to do is to simply download that QR code instead of showing in browser. You can use curl for this or, even simpler, just `fopen/file_get_contents` if `allow_url_fopen` is set to ON in php.ini

```
$image_bin = file_get_contents($qr_link);
file_put_contents($target_file_on_filesyste, $image_bin);
```